# $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{1}{2x}$, $\int^{3}_{1} \sqrt{1 +[f'(x)]^2}\, dx = ?$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$f(x) =  \frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{1}{2x}$$

$$\int^{3}_{1} \sqrt{1 +[f'(x)]^2}\, dx = ?$$

Let's start by deriving the function, we have

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{x^4-1}{2x^2}$$

Hence we get

$$\int^{3}_{1} \sqrt{1 +\Big[\dfrac{x^4-1}{2x^2}\Big]^2}\, dx = ?$$

Am I right?

---

**UPDATE:** 
If we have a definite integral:

$$\int^{3}_{1} \sqrt{1 +\Big[\dfrac{x^4-1}{2x^2}\Big]^2}\, dx = \dfrac{x^4-3}{6x}+C$$

Then

$$\dfrac{x^4-3}{6x}+C = \boxed{\frac{14}{3}}$$

Comment: Yes, please continue expanding it.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Am I right?

Comment: @Winther I'm updating the question right now. See the new edit.

Comment: @Winther Let me show it but where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Winther I think I corrected it right now.

Comment: @Winther Now Is the final answer wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Note that $$1+\left(\frac{x^4-1}{2x^2}\right)^2=\frac{(x^4+1)^2}{4x^4}$$

Comment: Is the answer $\frac{14}{3}$ correct?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$f(x) =  \frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{1}{2x}\implies f'(x)=\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac1{2x^2}$$
$$ \implies I=\int^{3}_{1} \sqrt{1 +[f'(x)]^2}\, dx =\int^{3}_{1} \sqrt{(\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac 1{2x^2})^2}\, dx $$
$$\implies I=\left . \frac {x^3}6-\frac 1 {2x}\right |^3_1 = \frac {14}3$$
And that you can't write this
$$\int^{3}_{1} \sqrt{1 +\Big[\dfrac{x^4-1}{2x^2}\Big]^2}\, dx = \dfrac{x^4-3}{6x}+C$$
since the integral is definite it's a number it can't be equal to a function...